# Graphviz directed graph: circle size depends of degree

Tags: networkx, graphviz

I am using `networkx` with `graphviz` to draw a DAG graph. What I am doing here is:

1. read a `graphML` graph
2. remove some nodes and edges based on some conditions
3. draw the graph using `graphviz`

What would be the most efficient way to to change the size of each circle depending of the number of ingoing edges + outgoing edges (degree)?

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout, to_agraph
from settings import (GRAPH_ML_PATH, MINIMUM_NODE_DEGREE, NODE_CATEGORIES, OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)


def remove_nodes(input_graph):
    nodes_to_remove = []
    for node, data in input_graph.nodes(data=True):
        if data['zone'] != 'gold' or input_graph.degree(node) < MINIMUM_NODE_DEGREE:
            nodes_to_remove.append(node)
    input_graph.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
    return input_graph


def draw_graph(networkx_graph):
    networkx_graph.graph['graph']={'rankdir':'TD'}
    networkx_graph.graph['node']={'shape':'circle'}
    networkx_graph.graph['edges']={'arrowsize':'4.0'}
    pygraphviz_graph = to_agraph(networkx_graph)
    pygraphviz_graph.layout('dot')
    pygraphviz_graph.draw(OUTPUT_FILE_PATH)


def build_graph():
    input_graph = nx.read_graphml(GRAPH_ML_PATH)
    g = remove_nodes(input_graph)
    print(type(input_graph))
    draw_graph(g)

build_graph()
```

result.dot (sample)

```
digraph "" {
    graph [bb="0,0,78779,3271.2",
        edge_default="{}",
        edges="{'arrowsize': '4.0'}",
        node_default="{}",
        rankdir=TD
    ];
    node [label="\N",
        shape=circle
    ];
    "gold_adhoc_demand_review.countries"    [height=4.0833,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="1295,1640.5",
        table=countries,
        use_case=demand_review,
        width=4.0833,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location"    [height=2.125,
        kind=core,
        pos="1114,2165.2",
        table=location,
        width=2.125,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_demand_review.countries"    [pos="e,1247.2,1779.5 1138.8,2092.6 1165.7,2014.8 1209.5,1888.3 1243.9,1789"];
    "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.distribution_network"    [height=5.4167,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="195,1640.5",
        table=distribution_network,
        use_case=product_priorities,
        width=5.4167,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.distribution_network"    [pos="e,311.08,1797.2 1039.3,2146.8 902.65,2112.2 607.02,2025.4 399,1877 370.21,1856.5 342.83,1831.1 318.01,1804.7"];
    "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.country"   [height=4.5278,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="1623,1640.5",
        table=country,
        use_case=global_supply_review,
        width=4.5278,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.country"   [pos="e,1532.7,1776.6 1175.3,2119.1 1245.8,2065.5 1363.3,1971.6 1451,1877 1477.2,1848.8 1503.1,1816.4 1526.5,1785"];
    "gold_adhoc_demand_planning.non_validated_tenders"  [height=5.5972,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="5789,1640.5",
        table=non_validated_tenders,
        use_case=demand_planning,
        width=5.5972,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_demand_planning.non_validated_tenders"  [pos="e,5591.1,1679.8 1168.3,2110.6 1234.5,2049.3 1352.9,1952.5 1476,1913 1620.6,1866.7 4057.6,1889.3 4209,1877 4704.1,1837.1 5279.7,1737.7 \
5580.9,1681.6"];
    "gold_adhoc_demand_planning.countries"  [height=4.2778,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="562,1640.5",
        table=countries,
        use_case=demand_planning,
        width=4.2778,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_demand_planning.countries"  [pos="e,641.52,1772.7 1048.3,2125.2 966.57,2074.7 825.52,1980.7 725,1877 697.07,1848.2 670.56,1814.2 647.35,1781.1"];
    "gold_adhoc_supply_chain_dashboard.market_served"   [height=5.5,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="932,1640.5",
        table=market_served,
        use_case=supply_chain_dashboard,
        width=5.5,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_supply_chain_dashboard.market_served"   [pos="e,996.93,1827.9 1089.1,2092.6 1066.2,2027.1 1031.4,1926.9 1000.3,1837.7"];
    "gold_core.pc_loc_country_mapping"  [height=3.8472,
        kind=core,
        pos="1623,2165.2",
        table=pc_loc_country_mapping,
        width=3.8472,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.pc_loc_country_mapping" -> "gold_adhoc_demand_review.countries"  [pos="e,1372.8,1765.5 1549.8,2047.6 1498.9,1966.5 1431.1,1858.4 1378.2,1774.1"];
    "gold_core.pc_loc_country_mapping" -> "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.country" [pos="e,1623,1803.7 1623,2026.5 1623,1961.4 1623,1882.9 1623,1813.8"];
    "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.results"   [height=4.4167,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="3016,1640.5",
        table=results,
        use_case=global_supply_review,
        width=4.4167,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.pc_loc_country_mapping" -> "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.results" [pos="e,2856.5,1647 1697.4,2048.1 1734.1,1999.5 1782.5,1946.7 1838,1913 2158.7,1718.7 2605.6,1663.4 2846.3,1647.6"];
    "gold_core.products"    [height=2.1806,
        kind=core,
        pos="7120,2862.2",
        table=products,
        width=2.1806,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_cover.skuloc_valuation"   [height=4.4583,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="7027,1640.5",
        table=skuloc_valuation,
        use_case=stock_cover,
        width=4.4583,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_cover.skuloc_valuation"   [pos="e,7098.7,1784.5 7198.3,2853.8 7510,2822.6 8656.7,2690.3 8869,2417.4 8903.4,2373.2 8908.2,1953.1 8869,1913 8804,1846.6 7279.2,1920.2 \
7197,1877 7160.1,1857.7 7129.3,1826.3 7104.5,1792.6"];
    "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.item"  [height=4.2222,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="3768,2165.2",
        table=item,
        use_case=global_supply_review,
        width=4.2222,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.item"  [pos="e,3828.2,2305.2 7041.1,2859 6603.1,2845.6 4469.2,2763.3 3929,2417.4 3889.6,2392.2 3858,2353.6 3833.6,2314.2"];
    "gold_core.stock_history"   [height=2.6528,
        kind=core,
        pos="4034,2165.2",
        table=stock_history,
        width=2.6528,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_core.stock_history"   [pos="e,4049.5,2259.6 7041.2,2859.7 6617.5,2849.9 4611,2784.7 4139,2417.4 4092.8,2381.5 4066.7,2321.5 4052.1,2269.2"];
    "gold_core.source_systems"  [height=2.8889,
        kind=core,
        pos="10967,2165.2",
        table=source_systems,
        width=2.8889,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_core.source_systems"  [pos="e,10948,2267.7 7196.4,2843 7481.9,2775.8 8513.7,2541.5 9379,2453.4 9460.5,2445.1 10786,2462.7 10854,2417.4 10902,2385.8 10929,2329.1 \
10945,2277.6"];
    "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.products"    [height=4.2083,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="7357,1640.5",
        table=products,
        use_case=product_priorities,
        width=4.2083,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.products"    [pos="e,7294.6,1778.6 7041.3,2859.8 6821.8,2851.1 6201.7,2792.8 5942,2417.4 5910.1,2371.3 5902.9,1953.2 5942,1913 5990.6,1863 7135.8,1910.6 \
7197,1877 7234.6,1856.4 7265.1,1822.7 7289,1787.1"];
    "gold_adhoc_capacity_tool_arklow.PRODUCT"   [height=4.8611,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="8685,2165.2",
        table=PRODUCT,
        use_case=capacity_tool_arklow,
        width=4.8611,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_capacity_tool_arklow.PRODUCT"   [pos="e,8598,2317.1 7198.2,2853.1 7421.4,2826.6 8073.3,2725.8 8501,2417.4 8535.4,2392.6 8566,2359.4 8591.9,2325.3"];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.dim_products"  [height=4.2083,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="8341,2165.2",
        table=dim_products,
        use_case=stock_policy,
        width=4.2083,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.dim_products"  [pos="e,8274.7,2301.7 7196.9,2845.7 7383.9,2804.6 7869.5,2678.2 8180,2417.4 8215,2388 8245,2349 8269.3,2310.5"];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.stock_valuation_finished_products" [height=6.2639,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="6762,691.66",
        table=stock_valuation_finished_products,
        use_case=stock_policy,
        width=6.2639,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.stock_valuation_finished_products" [pos="e,6537.5,714.36 7041.2,2860.1 6446.4,2851.2 2673.7,2780.2 2343,2417.4 2305.2,2376 2321.6,1964.9 2343,1913 2464.3,1618.3 2569.3,1558.6 \
2848,1403.9 3492.6,1046.1 5784.3,790.39 6527.5,715.37"];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.normative_inventory"   [height=4.9167,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="7299,691.66",
        table=normative_inventory,
        use_case=stock_policy,
        width=4.9167,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.normative_inventory"   [pos="e,7169.5,812.38 7041.3,2858.9 6670.7,2846.2 5103.9,2772 4811,2417.4 4775.3,2374.2 4784.5,1962.4 4811,1913 5252.7,1090.3 5775.4,1185 \
6680,953.19 6817.3,918 6865.1,969.29 6997,917.19 7055.6,894.06 7112.8,856.51 7161.5,818.69"];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.dim_product_life_cycle"    [height=5.1944,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="9994,691.66",
        table=dim_product_life_cycle,
        use_case=stock_policy,
        width=5.1944,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.dim_product_life_cycle"    [pos="e,10114,835.69 7196.5,2843.9 7482.4,2780.2 8515.3,2556.3 9379,2453.4 9446.7,2445.3 9943.6,2465.5 9992,2417.4 10072,2338.2 9946.5,\
1993.4 10025,1913 10088,1848.9 10366,1943.2 10427,1877 10569,1721.9 10484,1606.4 10427,1403.9 10368,1191.9 10225,980.29 10120,843.76"];
    "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.valuation_semi_finished_products"  [height=6.2083,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="10621,2165.2",
        table=valuation_semi_finished_products,
        use_case=stock_policy,
        width=6.2083,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_stock_policy.valuation_semi_finished_products"  [pos="e,10489,2345.8 7196.4,2843.3 7482,2777.2 8514.2,2546.4 9379,2453.4 9490.5,2441.4 10286,2464.1 10388,2417.4 10422,2401.8 10453,2378.8 \
10481,2352.8"];
    "gold_adhoc_capacity_tool_anpharm.PRODUCTS" [height=5.1944,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="9103,2165.2",
        table=PRODUCTS,
        use_case=capacity_tool_anpharm,
        width=5.1944,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.products" -> "gold_adhoc_capacity_tool_anpharm.PRODUCTS" [pos="e,9003,2323.6 7199,2859.1 7462.2,2848.8 8325.6,2786.9 8902,2417.4 8937.2,2394.8 8969.1,2363.9 8996.5,2331.5"];
    "gold_adhoc_material_safety_data_sheet.risks_dim_products"  [height=6.2222,
        kind=adhoc,
```

Comment: Can you post the resulting `dot` file?

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my post with the final dot file (```svg```).

Comment: File looks a bit incomplete and furthermore it is the result of the conversion by graphviz dot, so it is not the requested dot file.

Comment: Correct. I am now trying to extract the dot file from my script

Comment: Albert, I just updated my post with the correct ```dot```file and a large sample of that file

Comment: What algorithm/equation do you want to apply to the circle radius values?  e.g. rad=x*incoming + y*outgoing

Comment: yep. Just the sum of xincoming + youtgoing should be the radius. So a circle with 10 incoming and outgoing should be 10 times bigger than a circle with a single ingoing /outgoing edge

Answer (score 1):

**GVPR** is part of the Graphviz system.  Here is a **GVPR** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) program that seems to do what you ask.
After running **GVPR**, you need to feed the output into `neato -n` (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) to produce a visual result.
So, the **GVPR** program, copy it to a file named *adjustSizeByDegree.gvpr*:

```
N{
  if (hasAttr($, "shape") && $.shape=="circle"){
     // added 1 to width so nodes with degree==0 will not have rad==0
     // change if all nodes are connected
     $.width=1.+$.degree;
  }
}
```

Here is a (Linux) command line to run **gvpr** & **neato**:

```
gvpr -c -f adjustSizeByDegree.gvpr myfile.dot | neato -n -Tpng >myfile.png
```